# Cant change method's variables in Java objects

Tags: java, oop, variables, arraylist, methods

I have a problem with changing variable value in contact object. I'm trying to make a contact list but I can't change value of variables trought methods. I have editContact method which calls changeName method, both methods are passed ArrayList object trought reference so it shouldn't have problems with changing values trought ArrayList in main method, but problem is when I want to change object's name it won't change it. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
package telefonski_imenik;

public class Contact {
protected String name;
protected String lastname;
protected String number;

public Contact(String name, String lastname, String number) {
    setName(name);
    setLastName(lastname);
    setNumber(number);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setLastName(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastname;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return this.number;
}
}



package telefonski_imenik;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;



 public class TelefonskiImenik {

public static void createContact(String ime, String prezime, String broj, ArrayList<Contact> 
 ContactList) {
    Contact noviKontakt = new Contact(ime, prezime, broj);
    ContactList.add(noviKontakt);
}

public static void editContact(ArrayList<Contact> ContactList) {
    
    System.out.println("Unesite nove podatke");
    changeName(ContactList);
    
    
}

public static void changeName(ArrayList<Contact> ContactList) {
    
    Scanner novinput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Unesite staro ime");
    String oldName = novinput.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Unesite novo ime");
    String newName = novinput.nextLine();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ContactList.size(); i++) {
        if (ContactList.get(i).equals(oldName)) {
            ContactList.get(i).setName(newName);
        }
    }
    
    novinput.close();
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    ArrayList<Contact> ContactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Unesite podatke");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    String lastname = input.nextLine();
    String number= input.nextLine();
    
    createContact(name, lastname, number, ContactList);
    
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ContactList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(ContactList.get(i).getName());
        System.out.println(ContactList.get(i).getLastName());
        System.out.println(ContactList.get(i).getNumber());
    }
    
    
    editContact(ContactList);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < ContactList.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(ContactList.get(i).getName());
        System.out.println(ContactList.get(i).getLastName());
        System.out.println(ContactList.get(i).getNumber());
    }
    
    input.close();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to get the name of the object in your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ContactList.size(); i++) {
        if (ContactList.get(i).equals(oldName)) {
            ContactList.get(i).setName(newName);
        }
    }
```

```
ContactList.get(i).getName().equals(oldName)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, i was constantly using prior to that ContactList.get(i).name == oldName and it stil couldnt work prior to that, thanks for your answer it helped me!